# Do not display a service in the service detail window

Tags: nagios

I have lots of services defined. Sometimes I want to disable a service, but I do not want to remove the service definition. There are [flags](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#service) to disable the checks:

```
   active_checks_enabled            0
   passive_checks_enabled           0
```

But the flags are still being shown (see image):

[image: disabled service]

Is there a flag to avoid nagios to display the service? I can of course comment it out from the service definition, but I would prefer to use a flag instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think `register 0` should work so the service doesn't get registered with nagios

Answer (score 0):

After disabling active checks (makes the big X appear), simply submit a *passive* check result for that service.  Set the passive check to 'OK'.  I usually add the text "Resetting" so others watching will know why it suddenly went 'green'.  Doing this removes the failure from the "Problems" screen.  No config changes required.

To bring the check 'back'.  You simply enable active checks again.